# Clarification required in Javascript coercion example

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 1+1+'2';
console.log(a);
> 22

var a = 1+1+'2'+7;
console.log(a);
> 227

var a = 1+1+'2'+7+10;
console.log(a);
> 22710

var a = 1+1+'2'+7+10-2;
console.log(a);
> 22708
```

where is the 0 coming from in 22708? coercion example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hint is in the previous evaluation. `1+1+'2'+7+10-2` is equivalent to `((1+1)+'2'+7+10)-2`, or `"22710"-2`. While `+` is defined for both strings and numbers (it's addition when both arguments are numbers, concatenation in any other case), `-` is only defined for numbers; and so `"22710"` is coerced to number: `22710-2` is indeed `22708`.

Comment: If left is evaluated to (1+1) why right is not evaluated to (7+10) or (10-2)? Or is there different rules for right and left associations of string coercion?

Comment: Because it *is* evaluated left-to-right. `1+1` is `2`; `2+'2'` is `"22"`; `"22"+7` is `"227"`; `"227"+10` is `"22710"`. And finally, `"22710"-2` is `22708`, as explained in the answer. There is never a time where `7+10` is an expression here.

Comment: a=2, b=3, c=4;
a=b=c; In this example the evaluation happens from right to left, so I was getting confused in my original question example.
Thanks for the clarification, much appreciated

Comment: Look at the [operator table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)'s associativity column: assignment, conditional and several other operators are right-to-left because otherwise weird things happen; but all arithmetics happens left-to-right.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript handles the subtract and minus signs differently. You get the zero because it is taking `22710` and subtracting 2 to get `22708`.

So it goes from `2`
To `22`
To `227`
To `22710`
To `22710 - 2`
Which gives `22708`

The actual reason as to why is way over my head though.